# TFS Error TF401320 While Trying to reopen Bug Using rest API

Tags: rest, tfs, azure-devops, tfs-2015, azure-devops-rest-api

Hi I am trying to reopen (Close to New State) Bug using REST API batch operation in TFS .

My patch document is as below

```
[
    {
        "method":"PATCH","uri":"/_apis/wit/workItems/309?api-version=1.0","headers":{
        "Content-Type":"application/json-patch+json"
    },
    "body":
        [
            {
            "op":"add",
            "path":"/fields/System.State",
            "value":"New"
            },
            {
            "from":"add",
            "op":"add",
            "path":"/fields/System.Tags",
            "value":"abc,cde,efg"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I am getting below error,I find not much information in documentations Please be kind enough to help me to rectify this issue.

```
TF401320: Rule Error for field Resolved Reason. Error code: HasValues, LimitedToValues, SetByRule, InvalidNotEmpty.
```

p.s : similar method work fine to modify "New" Bug "Close"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clear ResolvedReason field value:

```
[
 {
    "op":"add",
    "path":"/fields/System.State",
    "value":"New"
   },
   {
    "op":"add",
    "path":"/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedReason",
    "value":""
   }

]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @starain-MSFT :)

Comment: Hi @starain-MSFT , I am getting slimier error (with same error code) when I use VSO node api too can I apply same above solution to VSO too? 
error ~~~
TF401320: Rule Error for field Bug Classification. Error code: Required, HasValues, LimitedToValues, AllowsOldValue, InvalidEmpty.

Comment: @Lalindu They are using the same REST API, so you can. You can open a new thread if you still have the issue.